# Powershell script or scheduled task for opening a database file and export its data to an Excel file

Tags: powershell

I am looking for help with this situation. I have a database file that acts as database for a program and I want to automate the process of generating, instead of, manual reports inside the program, creating them automatically with the parameters or configuration that the program has.

This could be done by performing a scheduled task or a PowerShell script (I already know that at some point both ways are similar).

What I've tried up to now is executing the following command in PowerShell but with no success as i am not too skilled at scripting :

```
Get-Content -LiteralPath C:\ProgramData\PROISER\ISASPSUS\datastore\dsfile.db | 
    Export-Csv C:\ProgramData\PROISER\ISASPSUS\datastore\dsfile.db .`
```

I would be very thankful if someone could actually help me.

Comment: Hi Santiago.  Can you elaborate a little further?  Are you looking for the `.db` file to literally be converted to `.csv` format and that's it?  Can you provide any error (copy/paste) into your [edit] to your question?  I'm a little confused by a couple of extra characters at the end of your command as well (.`)

Comment: (Just an FYI, I ran your code against a standard `.db` thumbnail file, and it successfully exported to `.csv` format, but I left out the .` at the end of your command.)

Comment: With that little change of taking out .` it brings me a bigger error than before. What im trying to do is to schedule and export any changes done to the file in the day.

Comment: Again, please [edit] your post and copy/paste the error you're getting explicitly into your question so we can see exactly what may be wrong.  Without the actual error, it's impossible to tell what's wrong - it works perfectly for me without any issue.

We may also need to see more of your code.  If the .` characters are necessary, it seems like you've got another issue going on outside of the command at hand.